# What does "hot tarry mess" mean

Tags: word-meaning

"the city is a hot tarry mess"

I have no clue what does "hot tarry mess" mean.

Comment: Where does this quote come from, and have you tried looking up any of the words?

Comment: @Joachim, it's from a 2023 'horror novel' called _Looking Glass Sound_ by Catriona Ward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it is meant fairly literally, "tarry" being the adjectival form of "tar". I've certainly seen days hot enough that shoes leave imprints in asphalt (tar being a major component of asphalt, a primary street material in the United States), and then gets tracked into cars or even into buildings.